# Can I store BLOB objects into a CLOB type column in Oracle DB without casting

Tags: xml, oracle, xml-parsing, ibm-mq, messagebroker

I am using WebSphere Message Broker which has a message flow that reads XML messages from a queue. If the messages is of NON STANDARD type (not as per XML standards) it is converted to BLOB object and audited to an Oracle database.

The problem is NON STANDARD messages instead of getting audited into d/b are falling into backout queue.

On investigating i came to know that the field storing the audited message in database is of CLOB type whereas the message flow is converting the NON STANDARD message into BLOB type.

I was wondering if it is possible without casting or conversion..

here is the code (in ESQL) where the NON STANDARD message is casted into BLOB type:

```
MOVE aonMSG TO "OutputRoot"."BLOB";
SET msgChar = aonMSG;
SET messageType = 'NON_STANDARD_MESSAGE';
SET msgChar = CAST(OutputRoot."BLOB"."BLOB" As CHAR CCSID 819 ENCODING  
OutputRoot.MQMD.Encoding );
```

Answer (score 0):

From a broker perspective you could bring the message in as a BLOB and then RCD it to XMLNSC later and throw an exception for non standard messages, that way on the catch path from your input node you have access to the actual input bitstream guaranteeing no conversion or casting.

Your code above is a bit confusing, assuming that aonMsg is part of the input treew then you are taking a UCS-2 portion of message tree and putting this in a folder named BLOB. You are then casting that as a CHAR (not a blob) with CCSID 819 and the queue managers encoding.

If you want to create a BLOB from an arbitrary portion of the tree you need to serialize it using something like "AS BITSTREAM".

Alternatively if you;re only issue is that conversion is happening on the way to Oracle you may find that you need to ensure that the columns are of the correct type and that the odbc.ini file is set up correctly.